# R matrix - row vector - column vector - different output - confusion

Tags: r

Please note the following R session.

```
    > z3 <- cbind(c(10,10,10,10));   
    > z3
         [,1]
    [1,]   10
    [2,]   10
    [3,]   10
    [4,]   10
    > m2
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    2    3
    [2,]    4    5    6
    [3,]    7    8    9
    [4,]   10   11   12
    > m2[,2]
    [1]  2  5  8 11
    > m3
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]   10   10   10    8
    [2,]    1    1    1    1
    > m3 %*% m2[,2];
         [,1]
    [1,]  238
    [2,]   26
    > m3 %*% z3; 
         [,1]
    [1,]  380
    [2,]   40
    >
```

Here m3 is a 2x4 matrix so it makes perfect sense that it can be multiplied by m2[,2] (the second column of m2) because m2[,2] is a 4x1 matrix (so they are compatible for multiplication). Now note that z3 is also a 4x1 matrix (like m2[,2]).

I would like to know why their presentations (of m2[,2] and z) are different (I mean the output I see when I just type z3 and when I just type m2[,2] at the R prompt). I find this difference strange. I like z3's presentation, I don't like m2[,2]'s presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you subset to 1 dimension, R just turns it into a vector. (Edit: it just simplifies. I.e., "returns to lowest possible dimension")

If you don't want this to happen, do `m2[,2,drop=FALSE]`

As a side note, `(1:4)%*%m2` works, as does `m2%*%(1:3)`. So it's nice that even if it drops the matrix representation, it'll do the work to make your math work.

Comment: Nice. Side note: what kind of a lexical/language element is this: `m2[,2,2,drop=FALSE]`? Looks like a function call (with named argument "drop" but [] cannot be a function call). Hm?

Comment: Yes, I noticed those multiplications work which made it look even stranger to me (its textual representation). Thanks again, just the answer I was looking for.

Comment: "[" is a function! Do `?"["` to get the help doc. In fact, try `methods("[")`. You'll see that different classes have different methods for this generic.

Comment: So I thought (about [). Thanks, I am just a beginner in R.